# Binance python websocket - no response

Tags: python, websocket, binance

I'm trying to run an example code for binance websocket api using python-binance and following this tutorial: https://livedataframe.com/live-cryptocurrency-data-python-tutorial/

Unfortunately i can't make it work. The websocket just doesn't respond what results in empty terminal without anything printed out.

I'm using python 3.7.8, PyCharm IDE, Windows 10

Please help, thanks!

```
import time
from binance.client import Client # Import the Binance Client
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager # Import the Binance Socket Manager

_API_KEY = "mykey"
_API_SECRET = "mykey"

client = Client(_API_KEY, _API_SECRET)

# Instantiate a BinanceSocketManager, passing in the client that you instantiated
bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)

# This is our callback function. For now, it just prints messages as they come.
def handle_message(msg):
    print(msg)

# Start trade socket with 'ETHBTC' and use handle_message to.. handle the message.
conn_key = bm.start_trade_socket('ETHBTC', handle_message)
# then start the socket manager
bm.start()

# let some data flow..
time.sleep(10)

# stop the socket manager
bm.stop_socket(conn_key)
```

In addition i can run this code, but websocket api doesn't seem to work for me.
Regards.

```
from binance.client import Client


_API_KEY = "key"
_API_SECRET = "key"

client = Client(_API_KEY, _API_SECRET)
btc_price = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="BTCUSDT")
# print full output (dictionary)
print(btc_price)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have removed erroneous information that I had unintentionally posted here. The rest of the post unfortunately no longer makes as much sense as before :/

Rest of the post without erroneous information:

To do that you can use unicorn-binance-websocket-api:

```
pip install unicorn-binance-websocket-api
```

Create a websocket connection to Binance:

```
from unicorn_binance_websocket_api.unicorn_binance_websocket_api_manager import BinanceWebSocketApiManager

binance_websocket_api_manager = BinanceWebSocketApiManager(exchange="binance.com")
binance_com_websocket_api_manager.create_stream('arr', '!userData', api_key=binance_com_api_key, api_secret=binance_com_api_secret)
```

And 4 more lines to print the received data records:

```
while True:
    oldest_stream_data_from_stream_buffer = binance_websocket_api_manager.pop_stream_data_from_stream_buffer()
    if oldest_stream_data_from_stream_buffer:
        print(oldest_stream_data_from_stream_buffer)
```

Just try this example: https://github.com/LUCIT-Systems-and-Development/unicorn-binance-websocket-api/blob/master/example_userdata_stream.py

Comment: Oliver, the library that he is using in the livedataframe tutorial is `python-binance` it is an unofficial library but it connects directly to the binance servers just as `unicorn-binance-websocket-api` Your answer looks good but the first line of your post seems to be false information. So maybe can you delete the 3rd party statement? Unless i am wrong here, than please clarify.

Comment: Livedataframe also offers a separate module https://pypi.org/project/livedataframe/, somehow I got that confused. Sorry for the wrong information!

Answer (score 1):

The latest version like `python-binance` v1.0.15 use:

```py
import asyncio

from binance import Client, ThreadedWebsocketManager, ThreadedDepthCacheManager
```

or

```py
from binance import AsyncClient, DepthCacheManager, BinanceSocketManager

client = Client (api_key, api_secret)
```

Check out: https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel Droguett Quezada, it should be this instead

```
async_client = await AsyncClient.create(api_key, api_secret)
```